# Por que o conteúdo das minhas divs não centralizam nem se ajustam ao tamanho dela ( da div )

Tags: html, css, css-display

[image: QUERO Q MINHYA PÁGINA FIQUE ORGANIZADA ASSIM, MAS O CONTEÚDO DAS DIVS SAÍ DO ESPAÇO DELS]

```css
#container {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
  justify-items: center;
}

#secao1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(228, 227, 233);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: darkkhaki;
}

#secao2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(228, 227, 233);
  background-color: rgb(153, 209, 0);
}
```

[image: O CONTEÚDO DAS DIVS NÃO RESPEITA SEU ESPAÇO]

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: Tem como explicar qual o seu problema. Todos os dias recebemos n formas de design, então sem uma explicação detalhada fica difícil de entender o problema.

Comment: Fiz a postagem da foto da página q eu quero fazer e logo em seguida tem a foto da página q eu tô fazendo

Answer (score 1):

Você também pode tentar usar o **Clearfix** após cada seção:

```
#secao1:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Esse comportamento acontece porque você definiu um `height` para as divs menor que o tamanho das images.
Basta definir o tamanho da imagem desejado. Utilizei 150px como exemplo e o resultado parece ter sido o resperado:

```
img {
width: 150px;
}

#secao1 {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
}

#secao2 {
    margin: 0 auto;
   width: 50%;
   text-align: center;
}

#secao3{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 50%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Também removi o `height` das divs.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: pq o text align não centraliza o p ?

Comment: A div está com a largura do tamanho da tela.Vc precisa definir a width da div para o tamanho desejado e, usar text-align:center para alinhar o texto centralizado dentro da div. Para centralizar  a div no meio da tela, você pode usar margin: 0 auto. Editei minha resposta com essas alterações

Comment: obrigado ^^, mas a margin solid acaba ficando só em 50% do da div tb, o que não é o que eu quero. Consegui centralizar o texto utilizando pading left e right, desse modo eu "espremo" o texto e como ele tá centralizado meio que quebra linha. VC SABERIA COMO ENQUADRAR O CONTEÚDO NO TAMANHO DA PAG SEM TER BARRA DE ROLAGEM VETRICAL ??

Comment: Você pode aplicar um height: 100vh; no body. Assim a altura dele fica do tamanho da tela.

Comment: apliquei. Aparentemente não mudou nada

Comment: Tem como você colocar em um repositorio no github pra dar uma olhada?